# ¿Cómo añadir el número de veces que aparece un valor?

Tags: r

Actualmente tengo una tabla

```
      df<- col
           1942
           1956
           1956
           1956
           1956
           1956
           1986
           2000
           2000
           2072
           2072
           2072
           2094
```

Me gustaría añadir una segunda columna donde refleje el número de veces que aparece cada número, una cosa así:

```
      df<- col   times
           1942    1
           1956    2
           1956    2
           1956    2
           1956    2
           1956    2
           1986    3
           2000    4
           2000    4
           2072    5
           2072    5
           2072    5
           2094    6
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo automáticamente con R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que el vector este ordenado, con R base se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
glns <- rle(df$col)$lengths
df$times <- rep(1:length(glns), times=glns)
df

    col times
1  1942  1
2  1956  2
3  1956  2
4  1956  2
5  1956  2
6  1956  2
7  1986  3
8  2000  4
9  2000  4
10 2072  5
11 2072  5
12 2072  5
13 2094  6
```

Detalle:

- Con `glns <- rle(df$col)$lengths` obtenemos un vector con las cantidades de años en cada grupo
- Con `rep(1:length(glns), times=glns)` generamos la secuencia final

Otra forma es usar la suma acumulada y comparar el vector consigo mismo pero desplazado en una posición:

```
df$id <- cumsum(df$col != c(-1, head(df$col,-1)))
```

Si no te importa que el número sea correlativo, una forma más sencilla es: `rank(df$col, ties.method="min")`.

Comment: Funciona !!! Muchas gracias Patricio!!